# How can we detect two touch events simultaneously in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to detect two simultaneous touch events or press events and fire the functions. It is like pubg only where we move and fire simultaneously.For that, I tried using onTouchStart on a View component but I was getting the same result which I get when I touch the first button when I was touching the other button while the first button was pressed.thank you

Comment: Sorry, my bad, deleting the comment.

Comment: I also need to do this, did you find any solutions?

Comment: Nah I didn't found any solution for react native CLI. Are you esing expo ?

Comment: I dont use expo but if there is an expo solution I'd be interested to see.

Comment: [link]https://snack.expo.io/VzgPSPzmw . This is a snack where I have created a  multi-touch demo and it is working perfectly fine. Expo environment pre-installs react-native gesture handler and react-native gesture handler is the library that helps in multi-touch. Let me know if you still have any doubt and if you understood it upvote the comment so other's can also know

Comment: Your example works in terms of touching the same button while long pressing, I am looking to be able to touch the other button as well.